# Pray to G-d in feminine (leshon nekeva)

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, grammar-dikduk

For some reason I remember there were sources strictly prohibiting turning to G-d as a woman. Of cause there are may be prophets metaphores etc. But I think it is at least not encouraged to describe G-d and pray to him as a woman. However I now cannot find the source.

Can someone point me to the specific source in Talmud or any other authoritative source confirming the point?

Comment: Some of this may be relevant: http://www.chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/2010/jewish/Is-G-d-a-He.htm

Comment: I'm not aware of a source prohibiting it, and in some way, I'm surprised that there would be one. While God has no "gender", one of the most common "feminine" forms of God's name, namely "Yah" (ends in kamatz heh, and the fact that the final heh is "mapik" - with a dot - indicates the feminine possessive form) is used quite a bit in davening. Another one of God's names, "Emet" is also "feminine".

Comment: @DanF ??? Yah is not feminine. Why would a name be possessive anyway?? The Mappik just shows the Hey is consonantal.

Comment: @DanF Also, for example, note the masculine usage in *T'hillim* ([68:5](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2668.htm#5)).

Comment: @DanF, by making it specifically feminine, it may be kind of a statement of gender as if G-d has one ח"ו, instead of being an artifact of the language and/or having some specific purpose or meaning [e.g.](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9939/jewish/Chapter-11.htm#showrashi=true&v=15) ...

Comment: @Yisha - I don't follow your point. We already do this by referring to God in the masculine such as "Av Harachman" and "Avinu Malkeinu".

Comment: @DanF, Since you can't be gender neutral in Hebrew, the language choice is male for the gender neutral intention. By specifically changing that, it may be a problem where you aren't just living in the limitations of the language. If, on the other hand there was a specific different intention (like the verse I linked) that might be different. Just exploring why it might not be surprising to find a source that finds it a problem. I don't know if one exists.

Comment: @Yishai - I'm not aware that a source exists for the very reason that you posit, i.e. that God has no gender, but in terms of language, we need to anthromorphize God so that we can understand God in our terms. Nonetheless, the choice of "Av" as opposed to "Eim" is a specific masculine noun, vs. almost every other usage where we use a pronoun (e.g. - hakodosh baruch hu vs hakedosha brucha hi) or a masculine verb ending. So, question is when we use "Av" aren't we saying specifically that God is male?

Comment: @DanF, we are emphasizing G-d's parental relationship with us. I don't think there is a good (traditional) Hebrew word that is neutral. Anyway, using a male appellation isn't a problem if it has a purpose, e.g. to emphasize a fatherly relationship. But if someone wanted to just arbitrarily change everything to feminine, I could see potential for a concern.

Comment: I find it interesting that when we talk of God's presence, we use the feminine 'shechina'.
Additionally, in Chassidic / Kabbalistic literature, it is understood that the 2 popular names, Adonai and Elohim represent the female and male 'characteristics' of Hashem.

Comment: Thanks guys but I am still under impression that I have seen the source prohibiting somehow speaking of god (praying?) in feminine terms. I am also not sure shekhina is a G-d's name, it may denote its presence only.

Comment: @zvi Can you tell us where you obtained this from. There exists din and rachamim which not necessarily mean male and female. Please see the sefer shaarai orah brought in the bais yosef of all the names of hashem and which 'sfiros' they represent.  https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=rabbi+yosef+gikatilla

Comment: @preferred for one example, see Nesivos Shalom's 2nd piece on Bereishis, where he discusses Bereishsi = Beis Reishis - dual creation.. –  Zvi yesterday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(נתיב הצניעות פרק א (מהר"ל:‏

> ..ועוד ראוי שיהיו בניו זכרים, כי הזכר מעלת מדרגתו נסתר וצנוע ביותר,
>   ומפני כך כאשר צנוע בדרכיו, ואז הוא מגיע עד המדרגה הנסתרת אשר בא משם
>   הזכר, כי הזכר בא ממדרגה נסתרת עליונה, אבל האשה לפי שפלתה אינה באה
>   ממקום נסתר עליון, ולכך זכר בגמטריא ברכה, וכל ברכה הוא בסמוי ובנסתר מן
>   העין, אבל הנקבה הפך זה, **שלשון נקבה כמו ויקב את השם שהוא קללה**, והוא
>   לשון נקבה שכרך עלי ואתנה, שהוא לשון מפורש, שהמפורש אינו סמוי, ולכך הוא
>   לשון קללה גם כן, ומפני כך אמרו עשרה קבין שיחה ירדו לעולם, ט' נטלו
>   נשים, וכל זה מפני שהדבור מוציא הכל אל הגלוי, וזה שייך באשה, שאין לה
>   מעלה העליונה הנסתרת... (נתיב הצניעות פרק א)‏